How to organize a C-project?
I am really not a c-programmer but I know the basic syntax.
I would like to download and debug a project in an IDE such as Code::Blocks.
If I download a project, say scrot-master from https://github.com/resurrecting-open-source-projects/scrot, it typically comes in the form of a root directory and the subdirectories doc, man and src.
Now I am at a total loss on how to organize and setup a project like this for Code::Blocks based on this structure and even more so on how to create a similar project.
Thanks in advance for any tip that helps me out.
H

So you already have an existing project which you can use as example and template, why not do it that way?

You just have to ensure that the IDE respect the directories. That is if you add a source file located as \foo\foo.c then the IDE needs to pass that path along to the compiler. Most sane IDEs do this. Insane IDEs like Eclipse will require you to manually set up all subdirectories explicitly, because those who made that IDE didn't anticipate that source code may be located in several different folders.
